# how to disabled kubernetes log to disk file?

Tags: kubernetes

I have tried

```
kubectl create -f x.yaml --logtostderr=true
```

but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Kubernetes API doesn't currently expose a way to change the logging behavior. It'll rotate the log files as appropriate to avoid filling up the disk, but if you need more control, you'll have to [modify the docker daemon on each node to change its logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/).

Or if you want to do it for a specific application, change the command in your x.yaml file that you're using to start the app to redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null inside the container.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but how to  redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null inside the container ?

Comment: By modifying the command or the args passed to the process, e.g. appending `&> /dev/null` to the end of the command. Alternatively: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32013582/1925481